# Linq 2 Sql with Sproc, as queryable, are any query tweaks turned into SQL or are they C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

So given some sproc on a datacontext say I do a..

```
from arr in someContext.MySproc() select arr.Hello, arr.Whoa where arr.Name = "grumbug"
```

If it was `from arr in someContext.MyTable` then the select and where would result in actual sql generation to select and where, but in the case of a sproc does it also result in sql generation that queries the sproc results on the DB server, or are the sproc results past back to the C# wholesale where the select and where is treated like a standard linq to collections select and where?

Comment: Well, profile the generated SQL and you will see. Put my money on simple execution of the SP.

Comment: @Pleun I'm wagering the same, but I don't have profiling tools on hand and am willing to bet there are many people here who know this right off the tops of their head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It execute the SP, and the rest of the query is done with Linq-to-object.

Here is the proof:

[image]

I executed a SP with EF in LinqPad. I Added a condition `Where(c => c.Part == 1)` to see if it affected the query send to the database. As you can see, it did not.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa your welcome. I really recommend LinqPad - its awesome for all types of query :)